# constructor Maestro in class Maestro cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

me da el error: constructor Maestro in class Maestro cannot be applied to given types; en la clase PruebaAdmonPersonal

El error casi hasta el ultimo en: p = new Maestro (id, nombre, sexo, fechaNac);

Soy nuevo programando en java y quisiera saber el porque me da ese error

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public   class PruebaAdmonPersonal {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
      int opc, id, horasContrato, celda, dato, resp;
      String nombre, fechaNac, puesto;
      char  sexo;
      AdmonPersonal ap = new AdmonPersonal();
      Personal p;
      
      
        do{
         System.out.println("\nUniversidad de CD. GUZMÁN");
         System.out.println("[1] CATALOGO DE MAESTROS");
         System.out.println("[2] CATALOGO DE OPERARIOS");
         System.out.println("[3] SALIR");
         System.out.println("¿Opcion deseada? [1-3]: ");
         opc = leer.nextInt();
         switch(opc) {
         case 1: //CATALOGO DE MAESTROS
         do{
         System.out.println("\nCATALGO DE MAESTROS");
         System.out.println("[1] ALTAS");
         System.out.println("[2] CONSULTA INDIVIDUAL");
         System.out.println("[3] CONSULTA GENERAL");
         System.out.println("[4] MODIFICACIONES");
         System.out.println("[5] BAJAS");
         System.out.println("[6] FINALIZAR");
         System.out.println("¿Opcion deseada? [1-6]: ");
         opc = leer.nextInt();
         switch(opc) {
            case 1: //ALTAS
                if(ap.hayEspacio()) {
                  System.out.println("\nALTAS");
                   System.out.print("ingrese el id del maestro a dar de alta");
                   id= leer.nextInt();
                   if(ap.validarId(id)) {
                     celda = ap.busqueda(id);
                     if(celda == -1) {
                     leer.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Id-----------: ");
                        id = leer.nextInt();
                        
                        System.out.print("Nombre-----------: ");
                        nombre = leer.nextLine();
                        
                        System.out.print("Sexo (H,M)-----------: ");
                        sexo = leer.nextLine().charAt(0);
                       
                        System.out.print("Fecha de  nacimiento(dd-mm-aaaa)-------: ");
                        fechaNac= leer.nextLine();
                        p = new Maestro (id, nombre, sexo, fechaNac);//Aqui da el error :constructor Maestro in class Maestro cannot be applied to given types;
                        ap.altas(p);
                        System.out.println("El alta se realizo con exito");
```

Clase Maestro

```
    public   class Maestro extends Personal {
   private String titulo;
   private int horasContrato;
   
   
   public Maestro(int id, String nombre, char sexo, String fechaNac, String titulo, int horasContrato) {
      super(id, nombre, sexo, fechaNac);
      this.titulo = titulo;
      this.horasContrato = horasContrato;
    }
    
    
      
    
    public String getTitulo() {
      return titulo;
    }
    
    public int getHorasContrato() {
      return horasContrato;
    }
    
    public void setTitulo(String Titulo) {
      this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    
    public void setHorasContrato(int horasContrato) {
      this.horasContrato = horasContrato;
    }
    
    public  float calcularSalario() {
    if (horasContrato >= 20) {
        return horasContrato * 210.50f;
        }else {
        return horasContrato * 183.50f;
        }
    }    
 }
```

Clase Personal

```
public abstract class Personal {
   private int id;
   private String nombre;
   private char sexo;
   private String fechaNac;
   
   public Personal (int id, String nombre, char sexo, String fechaNac) {
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.sexo = sexo;
      this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
     }
     
     public int getid(){
      return id;
     }
     
     public String getNombre(){
      return nombre;
     }
     
     public char getSexo(){
      return sexo;
     }
     
     public String getFechaNac(){
      return fechaNac;
     }
      public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
     public void setNombre(String nombre) {
         this.nombre = nombre;
     }
     
     public void setSexo(char sexo) {
         this.sexo = sexo;
     }
      public void setFechaNac(String fechaNac) {
         this.fechaNac= fechaNac;
     }
     public abstract float calcularSalario();
     
 }
```

Comment: Revisa el contructor de la clase `maestro`, has declarado que recibe: `public Maestro(int id, String nombre, char sexo, String fechaNac, String titulo, int horasContrato)` pero le estas mandando menos parámetros: `new Maestro (id, nombre, sexo, fechaNac)`